# ERT, equality test fails due to different symbols which must be considered same

Tags: unit-testing, emacs, elisp, ert

So, I'm trying to get familiar with ERT, the unit-testing package in Emacs. I want to test macro expansion which uses `gensym`. I can make sure that gensym produces symbols with the same *name*, but they are not the same symbol, which causes failure. Below is the code to give you better idea:

```
(ert-deftest i-test-repreat ()
  "Tests the expansion of i-iterate macro, repeat driver."
  (require 'i-iterate)
  (should
   (equal
    (macroexpand '(++ (repeat 100) (message "")))
    '(let* ((--0 0)) ;; `--0' is a result of a custom-made `gensym'
       (while (< --0 100)
         (incf --0)
         (message "")) nil))))
```

Here's the fail message:

```
(list-elt 1
  (list-elt 0
    (list-elt 0
      (different-symbols-with-the-same-name --0 --0))))
```

Fair enough, it is a different symbol, but it is expected to be so. How can I allow this to succeed?

**EDIT**

This is what I could come up with so far:

```
(defun i/test-equals-ignore-gensym (a b)
  "Tests trees A and B for equality, but considers symbols
equal if their names are equal (this allows symbols generated
by `i-gensym' to pass)."
  (or (equal a b)
      (cond
       ((and (null a) (null b)) t)
       ((and (consp a) (consp b))
        (and (i/test-equals-ignore-gensym (car a) (car b))
             (i/test-equals-ignore-gensym (cdr a) (cdr b))))
       ((and (symbolp a) (symbolp b))
        (string= (symbol-name a) (symbol-name b)))
       ((and (atom a) (atom b)) (eql a b))
       (t nil))))

(defun i/test-explainer-equal (a b)
  "Explains why `i/test-equals-ignore-gensym' failed."
  ;; TODO: Write our own explanation, this will trigger when
  ;; necessary, but will not always display the correct message.
  (ert--explain-equal-rec a b))
(put 'i/test-equals-ignore-gensym
     'ert-explainer 'i/test-explainer-equal)

(ert-deftest i-test-repreat ()
  "Tests the expansion of i-iterate macro, repeat driver."
  (require 'i-iterate)
  (should
   (i/test-equals-ignore-gensym
    (macroexpand '(++ (repeat 100) (message "")))
    '(let* ((--0 0))
       (while (< --0 100)
         (incf --0)
         (message "")) nil))))
```

But I would be happier if there was a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attack the problem differently: do not check whther the code is the one you expect, but instead only check whether the code behaves as you expect.  I.e. run the `(++ ...)` expression and check the output.

BTW, the comparison you want to do on those chunks of code is called "equality modulo alpha-conversion" or just [alpha equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_conversion#Alpha_equivalence)

Answer (score 0):

You could compare the actual names with `symbol-name`.

Comment: You can't call (symbol-name) on both the expected and actual values before passing them to ert?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `make-symbol` in your custom-made `gensym`, replacing `make-symbol` with `intern` helps you.  So,

```
(flet ((make-symbol (&optional prefix) (intern prefix)))
  (macroexpand '(++ (repeat 100) (message ""))))
```

generates similar code with symbol `--0` interned.  This is enough to avoid your problem.